# How do I write to a .cs file in c# and/or how to change the .txt to .cs

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want to write to a `.cs` file in C#. This is the (very basic) code I'm using:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter ("test.cs");   
file.WriteLine ("Console.WriteLine(\"It worked\")");
```

It successfully creates the file, but doesn't write anything to it.

Also, I was wondering if it's possible to change from .txt to .cs in any way?

To the person who said that this was a duplicate: The reason this is not a duplicate is that it is talking about writing to a `.cs` file, not a `.txt` which is what the other question talks about.

Comment: From what you have, it looks like it already is a `.cs` file. Also, please let me know if my clarification of how it's not working is incorrect -- I guessed.

Comment: It creates the .cs file but fails to actually write any strings to the file.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with [finished] or [answered]. Clicking the check mark does that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not flushing the stream, so it's not writing to the file.

There's a few ways to do it. Call `Flush` after the write, or set `AutoFlush = true`... or just surround it all with a `using` statement like this:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter ("test.cs"))
{
    file.WriteLine("Console.WriteLine(\"It worked\")");
}
```

As for the file extension, you're already specifying "test.cs", so that should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I thought this might have been a duplicate but I had searched for about 2 days with no success on figuring this out.